# WPA2-Enterprise / EAP-TLS user identity

Tags: wpa2-eap

I'm currently in process of testing EAP-TLS before deploying it in production. My test setup consists of:

- **Supplicants:** Android 6, Debian Buster with WICD-GTK.
- **Authenticator:** Mikrotik RouterOS 6.43 (actually it is passing through
  EAP frames to    FreeRADIUS)
- **Authentication server:** FreeRADIUS 3.0.12

It is known that the `CN` field in an `x509` user certificate can be used as a user identity. I supposed that with EAP-TLS we must not use username/password pair anymore. But in the case of Android or WICD I have to manually specify a username (`Identity`) in the client's Wi-Fi settings (Android, WICD) to be successfully authenticated. Furthermore, in the WICD-GTK GUI the `Identity` field can't be empty. Android does allow that field to be empty, but authentication is not working in such a case. In fact, in the `Identity` field I have to input the very same value as `CN` is. I heard that Apple iOS uses the CN value if `Identity` field is empty, but I've no Apple device for confirmation.

Is it normal behavior to require manual specification of a user's identity for EAP-TLS Wi-Fi settings, regardless of the CN value - or it is a poor EAP-TLS implementation in those clients?